# Copy last row to another spreadsheet upon form submission

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I would like to copy lastRows from 'Source1' sheet to 'Destination1' sheet. Triggers are on every change form 'Source1'.

The code below can help me to do the job.

```
function copyLastRow() {  
var target = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxx-keyfile').getSheetByName('Destination1'); // copy data into this file & sheet.
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Source1'); // name of source sheet. 
var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();
var sourceData = sheet.getRange(lastrow, 1,1, 37).getValues();
target.appendRow(sourceData[0]);}
```

I also set up another function as below. This function is for automatically clearing data from 'source 1' on specify time (e.g: everyday at 1 am).

```
function clearRange() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Source1');
sheet.getRange('A2:F').clearContent();}
```

When function clearRange() run at 1 am on everyday, data on 'source1' with range A2:F will be clear. At that moment, the range 'A1:F1' will be as the LastRow and it will be copied to 'Destination1' as the copyLastRow() function is still running.

What I would do is the copyLastRow() function don't copy the range A1:F1 as the LastRow.

I'm quite new in not only GAS but also JS...so I would appreciate if anyone could understand and help me to solve my problem.

The mentioned code above was copied from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26358310/copy-last-row-to-another-spreadsheet-upon-form-submission).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check to see if the first item in the sourceData Array is not the same value that is in A1 before you copy the data over. I am assuming this is a title row and that you don't have anyone named "name" in your data set.

```
var sourceData = sheet.getRange(lastrow, 1,1, 37).getValues();
if (sourceData[0][0] != sheet.getRange(1, 1).getValue();){
  target.appendRow(sourceData[0]);
  }
}
```

Comment: You save not only my day but also help me to improve my understanding on GAS. Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: Ah, I'm not quite clear on If statement. There are two [0][0] in the if condition? I don't know what does it mean? Could you please explain to me? 

    if (sourceData[0][0] != sheet.getRange(1, 1).getValue();){  (sourceData[0][0] != sheet.getRange(1, 1).getValue();){
  target.appendRow(sourceData[0]);
  }
}

Comment: The array is 2-D, which means there are arrays in the array [[data,data][data,data][data,data]] getting sourceData[0][0] is getting the first element of the first array. You will work with 2-D arrays a lot with google sheets.

Comment: Great to know that @Hink. :)